# When validation rule breaks, stop execution and focus form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When user clicks Ok button I validate it's input like:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myTxtField_Validated(this, e);
    myTxtField2_Validated(this, e);

    CustomObject obj = new CustomObject .....
}
```

Inside validation, I use error provider to inform user that input in fields must match certain criteria.

How can I silently break execution of this part `CustomObject obj = new CustomObject ....` if validation breaks. It works as expected with exist code for validation only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a private boolean member to achieve this easily and implement it like this:

```
private bool _validatedTextFields;
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myTxtField_Validated(this, e);
   myTxtField2_Validated(this, e);

   if (_validatedTextFields)
   {
   CustomObject obj = new CustomObject .....
   }
}

private void myTxtField_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //your validation...
  _validatedTextFields = true //only set your member to true if it has been validated.
}

private void myTxtField2_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //your validation...
  _validatedTextFields = true //only set your member to true if it has been validated.
}
```